# Simplier way to trigger HttpClient (maybe without Task)?

Tags: c#, asp.net-web-api, .net-core, task, dotnet-httpclient

Im working on app that will consume my own `REST endpoints` (i have my onw `WebApi` project). Now i try to build app that will work on this endpoint.

Based on [this](https://learn.microsoft.com/pl-pl/aspnet/web-api/overview/advanced/calling-a-web-api-from-a-net-client) MSDN tutorial i make something like this:

For testing, i make Console Core app. Main class look like this:

```
class Program
{
    public static HttpDataService http = new HttpDataService("authorization token here");

    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        Console.WriteLine("Hello World!");

        RunAsync().GetAwaiter().GetResult();
    }

    static async Task RunAsync()
    {
        var data = await http.Get("Default");
    }
}
```

My main `Http` class looks like this:

```
public class HttpDataService
{
    public HttpDataService(string token)
    {
        this.HttpClient = new HttpClient();
        this.HttpClient.DefaultRequestHeaders.Authorization = new AuthenticationHeaderValue("Bearer", token);
    }

    private HttpClient HttpClient { get; set; }

    public async Task<object> Get(string controller)
    {
        object data;
        HttpResponseMessage response = await this.HttpClient.GetAsync(UrlService.BuildEndpoint(controller));

        if (response.IsSuccessStatusCode)
        {
            data = await response.Content.ReadAsAsync<object>();
            return data;
        }
        else
        {
            throw new Exception(); //todo
        }
    }
}
```

I didnt like additional step, that i need to do method for run task (`RunAsync.GetAwaiter...` in Main method).

Is there simplier way to consuming my own endpoints? Maybe some other lib, that dont need to have additional method (in this way, `static Async Task Run`)? Is there way to just trigger method like:

```
http.Get("Projects");
```

Without `RunAsync()` method that i write before?

PS. that console app works ok (i get values from `Default` controller from my WebApi proj)

**EDIT**

That way looks more user-friendly:

```
static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        Console.WriteLine("Hello World!");

        Task get = http.Get("default");

        RunAsync(get).GetAwaiter().GetResult();
    }

    static async Task RunAsync(Task endpoint)
    {
         await endpoint;
    }
```

but how to get that from `endpoint`?

Comment: So if I understand you correctly, you want to get rid of the `RunAsync(get).GetAwaiter().GetResult()`?

Comment: Exactly, is it possible, i want to remove that `RunAsync.GetAwaiter....` lines. I think about making wrapper for it. For example, make another class, `RestService`, there public methods for `GET, POST` etc., in this `Rest` class i will be triggering `HttpDataService` methods. In `RestService` class i will wrap that `RunAsync` thing. Not perfect, but will be more elegant and easier to write

Comment: Or meaybe there is another library to consume `api` in C#?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are 2 issues with your code. The first one is that your `RunAsync` method returns `Task` while your method `HttpDataService.Get` return `Task<object>`. To get your result from the endpoint, `RunAsync` should return `Task<object>`. When you await this task, you will get an object with your result.

For the `.GetAwaiter().GetResult()`, there are 2 options. Firstly, you could create a `static async Task MainAsync` where you run all your code and call this method from the non-sync `Main`-method by invoking `MainAsync().GetAwaiter().GetResult()`. Before C# 7.1, this was the way to go.

```
static void Main(string[] args)
{
    MainAsync(args).GetAwaiter().GetResult();
}

static async Task MainAsync(string[] args)
{
    // Run your async code here
}
```

If you use C# 7.1, you can make your `Main`-method async (`static async Task Main(string[] args)`) and from there you can call your async code directly.

```
static async Task Main(string[] args)
{
    // Run your async code here
}
```

Comment: My `console` app is sandbox only for testing. My main project will be `WPF`

Comment: Same goes for a WPF-project. The entrypoint of you app will also be a static Main-method. By using C# 7.1, you can make that method async as I described in my answer

Comment: Im using C# 7.3 (because of tuple return). So, even in wpf app i can make some methods `async` and then do something like `var result = http.Get();`?

Comment: Yes, you definitely can! If my answer was your solution, please consider to mark in as the accepted answer

Comment: If you wish, you can check my second question here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55948085/generic-taskobject-method

Answer (score 1):

Your can use an helper class

```cs
public static class AsyncHelper  
{
    private static readonly TaskFactory _taskFactory = new
        TaskFactory(CancellationToken.None,
                    TaskCreationOptions.None,
                    TaskContinuationOptions.None,
                    TaskScheduler.Default);

    public static TResult RunSync<TResult>(Func<Task<TResult>> func)
        => _taskFactory
            .StartNew(func)
            .Unwrap()
            .GetAwaiter()
            .GetResult();

    public static void RunSync(Func<Task> func)
        => _taskFactory
            .StartNew(func)
            .Unwrap()
            .GetAwaiter()
            .GetResult();
}
```

Allowing you to do that :

```cs
static async Task RunAsync(Task endpoint) {
   AsyncHelper.RunSync(() => endpoint());  
}
```

PS. have a look here [Ms AsyncHelper](https://github.com/aspnet/AspNetIdentity/blob/master/src/Microsoft.AspNet.Identity.Core/AsyncHelper.cs) and here [C# Async Tips & Tricks](https://cpratt.co/async-tips-tricks/)

Answer (score 1):

You should make `Main`  async.

*note* : works only with modern c#

```
static async Task Main(string[] args)
{
    var result = await http.Get("default");
}
```