# Generic Task<object> method

Tags: c#, generics, task

I have class to consuming my `REST` service.

Method for this will look like this:

```
public async Task<object> Get(string controller)
    {
        object data;
        HttpResponseMessage response = await this.HttpClient.GetAsync(UrlService.BuildEndpoint(controller));

        if (response.IsSuccessStatusCode)
        {
            data = await response.Content.ReadAsAsync<object>();
            return data;
        }
        else
        {
            throw new Exception(); //todo
        }
    }
```

in this case, `object` can be like my own class (`Project`, `User` etc) with propertys.

My question is, how to make `Task<object>` methods to be generic, that will take kind of objects that i want to (and return it)?

**EDIT**

When i do something like:

```
public async Task<TObject> Get<TObject>(string controller)
    {
        TObject data;
        HttpResponseMessage response = await this.HttpClient.GetAsync(UrlService.BuildEndpoint(controller));

        if (response.IsSuccessStatusCode)
        {
            data = await response.Content.ReadAsAsync<object>();
            return data;
        }
        else
        {
            throw new Exception(); //todo
        }
    }
```

i get an error on `await repsonse.Contet...`:

> Cannot implicity convert `object` to `TObject`...

Comment: What is your api returning? Json?

Comment: I dont know to be honest. I have clear `WebApi` project. From controllers, i returns model's objects. I belive its Json, becuase its how it looks from response

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use generic types:

```cs
public async Task<TObject> Get<TObject>(string controller)
    {
        TObject data;
        HttpResponseMessage response = await this.HttpClient.GetAsync(UrlService.BuildEndpoint(controller));

        if (response.IsSuccessStatusCode)
        {
            data = await response.Content.ReadAsAsync<TObject>();
            return data;
        }
        else
        {
            throw new Exception(); //todo
        }
    }
```

Have a look [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/programming-guide/generics/) and [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/programming-guide/generics/generic-methods) for more infos ;)

Comment: I would also invert if )

Comment: you missed the `TObject` in the `response.Content.ReadAsAsync<TObject>();` line ! ;)

Answer (score 1):

The following code would work:

```
public async Task<TObject> Get<TObject>(string controller)
{
    HttpResponseMessage response = await this.HttpClient.GetAsync(UrlService.BuildEndpoint(controller));

    if (response.IsSuccessStatusCode)
    {
        return await response.Content.ReadAsAsync<TObject>();
    }
    else
    {
        throw new Exception(); //todo
    }
}
```

Comment: please look at the suggested answers before posting new identical answers. Comments are there to mention typos

Comment: I did. Your answer just wasn't there yet when I started writing mine. Apologies

Answer (score -1):

Instead of "object" use a "T" type placeholder.

Try this:

```
  public async Task<T> Get (string controller)
  {
     T data;
     HttpResponseMessage response = await this.HttpClient.GetAsync (UrlService.BuildEndpoint (controller));

     if (response.IsSuccessStatusCode)
     {
        data = await response.Content.ReadAsAsync<T> ();
        return data;
     }
     else
     {
        throw new Exception (); //todo
     }
  }
```